# How to use multiple buffers in gltf 2.0?

Tags: buffer, sandbox, babylonjs, gltf

- I try to use multiple buffers to include different bin files(one for geometry data, one for animation data) but the animation bin file in buffers1 does not work in Babylonjs [*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined*].
- My questions are: Is there something wrong in my gltf file? How to use multiple bin file in gltf?
  Below is my complete gltf file:
- [And the bin files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnAD4ZhzLB0chBsv0YUCSmzBMuRm?e=bnh5Zb)

```
{
  "accessors": [
    {
      "bufferView": 0,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "type": "VEC3",
      "max": [
        0.3,
        0.3,
        0.3
      ],
      "min": [
        -0.3,
        -0.3,
        -0.3
      ],
      "name": "Positions Accessor"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 1,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "type": "VEC3",
      "name": "Normals Accessor"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 2,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "type": "VEC2",
      "name": "UV Accessor 0"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 3,
      "componentType": 5125,
      "count": 36,
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "name": "Indices Accessor"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 4,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 3,
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "max": [
        2.0
      ],
      "min": [
        0.0
      ],
      "name": "Animation Sampler Input"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 5,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 3,
      "type": "VEC3",
      "name": "Animation Sampler Output"
    }
  ],
  "animations": [
    {
      "channels": [
        {
          "sampler": 0,
          "target": {
            "node": 0,
            "path": "translation"
          }
        }
      ],
      "samplers": [
        {
          "input": 4,
          "output": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "asset": {
    "generator": "glTF Asset Generator",
    "version": "2.0"
  },
  "buffers": [
    {
      "uri": "Test_Geometry.bin",
      "byteLength": 912
    },
    {
      "uri": "Test_Animation.bin",
      "byteLength": 48
    }
  ],
  "bufferViews": [
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "name": "Positions"
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 288,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "name": "Normals"
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 576,
      "byteLength": 192,
      "name": "Texture Coords 0"
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 768,
      "byteLength": 144,
      "name": "Indices"
    },
    {
      "buffer": 1,
      "byteLength": 12,
      "name": "Animation Sampler Input"
    },
    {
      "buffer": 1,
      "byteOffset": 12,
      "byteLength": 36,
      "name": "Animation Sampler Output"
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "uri": "Test/MultipleBuffers.png"
    }
  ],
  "materials": [
    {
      "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
        "baseColorTexture": {
          "index": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meshes": [
    {
      "primitives": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "POSITION": 0,
            "NORMAL": 1,
            "TEXCOORD_0": 2
          },
          "indices": 3,
          "material": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "mesh": 0
    }
  ],
  "scene": 0,
  "scenes": [
    {
      "nodes": [
        0
      ]
    }
  ],
  "textures": [
    {
      "source": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the two `bin` files?  Also have you tried running this through the glTF-Validator, or loading in VSCode with the glTF extension installed?

Comment: Does the file work in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, and does it pass validation on http://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/?

Comment: @emackey Yes, I loading it in VSCode, and here is the error [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined].

Comment: @DonMcCurdy It does not pass in validator: `{"code": "ACCESSOR_ANIMATION_INPUT_NEGATIVE","message": "Animation input accessor element at index 0,1,2 is negative: -0.30000001192092896.","pointer": "/accessors/4"},
`

Comment: @DonMcCurdy There is also another error: `{"code": "ACCESSOR_ELEMENT_OUT_OF_MIN_BOUND","message": "Declared minimum/max value for this component does not match actual minimum/max.","pointer": "/accessors/4/min/0"}`. Even though I change the min and max value to the actual value(-0.3), It also have the error `ACCESSOR_ANIMATION_INPUT_NEGATIVE`